# 2 ISNULLS IN A SELECT

Tags: t-sql, isnull

Is there a better way to do this or is this code ok?

```
DECLARE  @Test DECIMAL(18,2) = NULL
        , @Test1 DECIMAL(18,2) = '5'

SELECT ISNULL(@Test,(ISNULL(@Test1,'0')))
```

Thanks,
EB

Comment: Also, don't assign a varchar to a decimal. Just assign a number.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for nesting `ISNULL`. You could use [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql):

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL

```
DECLARE @Test DECIMAL(18,2) = NULL , @Test1 DECIMAL(18,2) = 5;
SELECT COALESCE(@Test, @Test1, 0);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad1bb739e9af632243ee7ee5b64d4db6)**